# Strange behaviour with MySQL and PHP pdo, whats wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'll try to be concise and only show relevant information here:

I have two nearly identical pieces of code, one which works and the other not.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM active_notifications WHERE direction = '>' AND $usdCurrent > trigger_price AND currency = '$'");
$query->execute();  
var_dump($query);

$result = $query->fetchall((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
var_dump($result);
```

The above code works, when I var dump the query it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM active_notifications WHERE direction = '>' AND 182.62000 > trigger_price AND currency = '$'
```

My problem occurs when I try with a slightly different piece of code where I swap the $ symbol for a £ symbol

Here is the code:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM active_notifications WHERE direction = '>' AND $gbpCurrent > trigger_price AND currency = '£'");
$query->execute();  
var_dump($query);

$result = $query->fetchall((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

var_dump($result);
```

When I var dump the query I get this:

```
SELECT * FROM active_notifications WHERE direction = '>' AND 114.19942 > trigger_price AND currency = '£'
```

So all is correct up to this point,

When I run either created query directly in PhpMyAdmin the expected results are returned, However when I var_dump the $result of the £gbp query I get a null array.

At first I though it might be because I was reusing variable names but I tried both in complete isolation, the USD query always works and the GBP never works and always results in a null array being returned.

Like I said both of the generated queries work correctly in PhpMyAdmin (when run directly against the database)

The only difference is that in one query I have a £ symbol and the other I have a $ symbol,

Is the £ symbol some kind of disallowed symbol in PHP or something like that?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Check php and mysql character encodings. I'm thinking that your php's `£` is not the same as your mysql's `£`. Ideally, you'd avoid all the mess by using `gpb`, `usd`, etc... for the currency field.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How do I do that?

Comment: You legend, I just slapped this into my pdo init : PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8" and all is good hopefully this is correct? seems to work, if you want to put an answer i'll mark as correct cheers

Comment: There you go! :)  You might want to write it as an answer (it doesn't matter it was your question) in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: OP.Why you not using prepared query's?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone because i'm a PHP retard, i'll check them out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check php and mysql character encodings. I'm thinking that your php's `£` is not the same as your mysql's `£`.

Ideally, you'd avoid all the mess by using `'gpb'`, `'usd'`, etc... for the currency field.

From the OP:

> I just slapped this into my pdo init : **PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"** and all is good.